# Object with numeric keys will send all previous numbers anyways

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, arrays, object

Actually i have some trouble defining some clearly title for this question.

I have an array with one object as value defined by a numeric key (22895 in this case). Now what happens if i send this array through an Ajax, PHP will retrieve an array with 22895 keys where the first 22894 of it are empty.

Am i doing something wrong with defining the JS-Array/Object or whats the fix for this case?

My Console-Output (Browser) looks like this:

[image]

While the PHP Debug shows the following:

[image]

I guess its obvious: I need the Array to contain only the one sent value (with keeping key assignment)

**Edit**:
This is how i'm doing the Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    url: baseurl + '/module/functionName',
    context: this,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
        splitTicket: {
            tasks: Review.splitTicket.data.tasks
        }
    }
(...)
```

Comment: "i send this array through an Ajax" - please show us how exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how `$.param` works. If it sees an Array, it assumes it to be a "normal" dense one:

```
 data=[]; data[10]=99;
 $.param({t:data})
```

returns

```
"t%5B%5D=undefined&t%5B%5D=undefined&t%5B%5D=undefined&t%5B%5D=undefined&t%5B%5D=undefined&t%5B%5D=undefined&t%5B%5D=undefined&t%5B%5D=undefined&t%5B%5D=undefined&t%5B%5D=undefined&t%5B%5D=99"
```

Convert your array to an object to avoid this:

```
$.param({t:$.extend({}, data)})
```

Result:

```
"t%5B10%5D=99"
```

To do this recursively

```
var ary2obj = function(obj) {
    if($.isArray(obj))
        return ary2obj($.extend({}, obj));
    if($.isPlainObject(obj)) {
        var res = {};
        $.each(obj, function(k, v) {
            res[k] = ary2obj(v);
        });
        return res;
    }
    return obj;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CAv9P/

Comment: And how to avoid this?

Comment: Is there a way to apply that recursive?